# A problem in Xamarin.forms with an icon.png "Cannot decode image. The image must be a Bitmap"

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.forms, bitmap

i have a problem in my Xamarin's app, i tried to put pins (like an image.png (this images.png are in Resources/drawables folder)) in googlemaps, but when i try to do this the app enter in break mode and shows "Cannot decode image. The image must be a Bitmap".

I have the views, viewsModels and the next code in a class library (i think is xamarin.forms) and here i can't use the library Android.Graphics or install the nuget package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Map and neither use System.Drawing.Bitmap because when i try to use Bitmap's method(Bitmap.FromFile(), Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image.png), BitmapFactory, etc.) show an exception "The operation is not supported by platform".

I tried to convert the png to base64, byte[] array or stream and then to Bitmap but when i put then name of the image "pin_blue.png" or the path (just to test) the app show an exception "cannot find the file" or "Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: stream" (for stream).

I tried many things for days and i don't have success

```
//this is my pin class
public class PinCustom : Pin
    {
        public string TypePointOfInterest { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public Bitmap { get; set; }
        //Here  i create this variable to save a bitmap but i don't know if i do the things well
    }
```

```
//here i try to save the image.png in Icon
PinsFiltered= Pins = new List<PinCustom>(resultPointsOfInterest.Select(
                    x => new PinCustom()
                    {
                        Position =
                            new Position(x.ccsm0166latitud, x.ccsm0166longitud),
                        Address = x.ccsm0166direccion,
                        Label = x.ccsm0166nombre,
                        Type = PinType.Place,
                        TypePointOfInterest = x.ccsm0166tipositio,
                        Icon =  Int32.Parse(x.ccsm0166tipositio) == (int)PointOfInterestType.branch ? "pin_blue.png" : ic_pin_blue.bmp"
                           
                    }).ToList());
```

Comment: there is nothing new here that is not included in your previous question.  I have asked you repeatedly if you have tried the Xamarin custom pin sample - have you?  Does it work?  Have you compared what you are doing with what it does?  Do you understand that the custom renderer is code that is contained in the **Android** project, not the **Forms** project?

Comment: yes, i tried, i understand that but in the project where i am working, i need to do in Form's part, because is an existing project and i can't do in the android's part for a problem of dependencies